# SQL Injection example PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have been trying (for some time since yesterday) to inject SQL to a PHP web application example without success. I am not able to discover where my problem is. 
The first thing I did was to set the following in /etc/php/apache2/php.ini configuration file to turn off PHP SQL injection protection:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

After changing the above setting I restarted the Apache server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The application asks for an Employee ID and Password, and the information I type is:

```
' or '1=1
```

I have tried other options like:

```
xxx' or '1=1
' or ''='
```

I have even tried the above in both fields, Employee ID and Password.

I know that the web application works because I get access if I enter the correct credentials.

I have reviewed several posts here but I still cannot see my mistake. I will very much appreciate any clue to get my test run successfully.

The PHP code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- link to ccs-->
<link href="style_home.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class=wrapperR>
<p>
<button onclick="location.href = 'logoff.php';" id="logoffBtn" >LOG OFF</button>
</p>
</div>


<?php
   $input_eid = $_GET['EID'];
   $input_pwd = $_GET['Password']; 
   $input_pwd = sha1($input_pwd);

   // check if it has exist login session
   session_start(); 
   if($input_eid=="" and $input_pwd==sha1("") and $_SESSION['name']!="" and $_SESSION['pwd']!=""){
      $input_eid = $_SESSION['eid'];
      $input_pwd = $_SESSION['pwd']; 
   } 

   $conn = getDB();

   /* start make change for prepared statement */
   $sql = "SELECT id, name, eid, salary, birth, ssn, phoneNumber, address, email,nickname,Password 
           FROM credential 
           WHERE eid= '$input_eid' and Password='$input_pwd'";
   if (!$result = $conn->query($sql)) {
       die('There was an error running the query [' . $conn->error . ']\n');
   }

   /* convert the select return result into array type */ 
   $return_arr = array();
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       array_push($return_arr,$row);
   }

   /* convert the array type to json format and read out*/ 
   $json_str = json_encode($return_arr);
   $json_a = json_decode($json_str,true);
   $id = $json_a[0]['id'];
   $name = $json_a[0]['name'];
   $eid = $json_a[0]['eid'];
   $salary = $json_a[0]['salary'];
   $birth = $json_a[0]['birth'];
   $ssn = $json_a[0]['ssn'];
   $phoneNumber = $json_a[0]['phoneNumber'];
   $address = $json_a[0]['address'];
   $email = $json_a[0]['email'];
   $pwd = $json_a[0]['Password'];
   $nickname = $json_a[0]['nickname'];
   if($id!=""){
    drawLayout($id,$name,$eid,$salary,$birth,$ssn,$pwd,$nickname,$email,$address,$phoneNumber); 
   }else{
    echo "The account information your provide does not exist\n"; 
    return;
   }
   /* end change for prepared statement */ 

   $conn->close();  

function getDB() {
   $dbhost="localhost";
   $dbuser="root";
   $dbpass="seedubuntu";
   $dbname="Users";


   // Create a DB connection
   $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error . "\n");
   }
return $conn;
}

function   drawLayout($id,$name,$eid,$salary,$birth,$ssn,$pwd,$nickname,$email,$address,$phoneNumber){ 
   if($id!=""){
       session_start(); 
           $_SESSION['id'] = $id;   
       $_SESSION['eid'] = $eid;
           $_SESSION['name'] = $name;   
       $_SESSION['pwd'] = $pwd;
   }else{
    echo "can not assign session";
   }
   if ($name !="Admin") {
    echo "<br><h3> $name Profile</h3>";
    echo "<table>"; echo "<tr>"; echo "<td>Employee ID</td>";
    echo "<td>$eid</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Salary</td>";
    echo "<td>$salary</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Birth</td>";
    echo "<td>$birth</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>SSN</td>";
    echo "<td>$ssn</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>NickName</td>";
    echo "<td>$nickname</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Email</td>";
    echo "<td>$email</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Address</td>";
    echo "<td>$address</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Phone Number</td>";
    echo "<td>$phoneNumber</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
   }
   else {
        $conn = getDB();
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, eid, salary, birth, ssn, password, nickname, email, address, phoneNumber 
           FROM credential"; 
    if (!$result = $conn->query($sql)) {
            die('There was an error running the query [' . $conn->error . ']\n');
    }
    $return_arr = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            array_push($return_arr,$row);
    }
    $json_str = json_encode($return_arr);
    $json_aa = json_decode($json_str,true);
        $conn->close(); 
        $max = sizeof($json_aa);    
        for($i=0; $i< $max;$i++){
       //TODO: printout all the data for that users.        
       $i_id = $json_aa[$i]['id']; 
       $i_name= $json_aa[$i]['name']; 
       $i_eid= $json_aa[$i]['eid']; 
       $i_salary= $json_aa[$i]['salary']; 
       $i_birth= $json_aa[$i]['birth']; 
       $i_ssn= $json_aa[$i]['ssn']; 
           $i_pwd = $json_aa[$i]['Password'];
       $i_nickname= $json_aa[$i]['nickname']; 
       $i_email= $json_aa[$i]['email']; 
       $i_address= $json_aa[$i]['address']; 
       $i_phoneNumber= $json_aa[$i]['phoneNumber']; 
       echo "<br><h4> $i_name Profile</h4>";
       echo "Employee ID: $i_eid     ";
       echo "salary: $i_salary     ";
       echo "birth: $i_birth    ";
       echo "ssn: $i_ssn    ";
       echo "nickname: $i_nickname";
       echo "email: $i_email";
       echo "address: $i_address";
       echo "phone number: $i_phoneNumber";
    }
   }
}
?>

<div class=wrapperL>
<p>
<button onclick="location.href = 'edit.php';" id="editBtn" >Edit Profile</button>
</p>
</div>


<div id="page_footer" class="green">
<p>
Copyright &copy; SEED LABs
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Password hashing with SHA1 is insecure. Instead use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) functions.

Comment: Try: `1';--` for the userid and anything for the password. That should get you logged in as the user with eid 1.

Comment: As user name you can enter `' or '1' = '1` you need to consume the 2nd `'` too.

Comment: @AlexHowansky not sure if that is working with the semi-colon, at least for oracle (oci) you cannot add `;` at the end or the query gets rejected.

Comment: I was wrong, you should enter it as password, because `and` binds stronger than `or`.

Comment: `magic_quotes_gpc` went away in PHP 5.4.

Comment: @maraca You're correct, mysqli doesn't allow multiple queries in a single call, unless you use `mysqli_multi_query()`.

Comment: What does a testing tool like [SQLMap](http://sqlmap.org) find? Also `gpc_magic_quotes` aren't "SQL injection protection". Like register globals, this was a **severely** misguided idea that was so bad in practice it got removed from PHP. It gave people a false sense of security and was easily circumvented.

Comment: Nothing works. I printed out (echo) the query that includes the SQL injection and this is what it has: SELECT id, name, eid, salary, birth, ssn, phoneNumber, address, email,nickname,Password FROM credential WHERE eid= '\' or \'1\' = \'1' and Password='c76dc7c88323292ad89cb8ebae9ea1e2a0aef679'  (I am sorry, I do not know how to highlight the portion of code here). I am new to all this PHP and MySQL stuff. What are the backslashes doing in the query string?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
' or '1' = '1'; --
```

Please take into account that there must be a space after the second dash, this is a syntax requirement for a comment.

Thanks Alex Howansky, your response guided me to the solution.